# How to input date and time in a Vuetify text input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am attempting to build a Vuetify form that enables inputting of a date format that includes both the date and specific time of the event, for both starting and ending. So far, I have the following:

```
            <v-form @submit.prevent="addEvent">
              <v-text-field v-model="eventName" type="text" label="event name (required)"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="start" type="date" label="start (required)"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field v-model="end" type="date" label="end (required)"></v-text-field>
              <v-btn type="submit" color="primary" class="mr-4" @click.stop="dialog = false">
                Add Event
              </v-btn>
            </v-form>
```

Is there an input type that allows both date and time to be inputted into the same input field? If so, how can I implement such a field? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are Vuetify components for picking a date and time, but no combined one.

There is a basic html component you could check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Otherwise you'll have to make a custom one.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there an input type that allows both date and time to be inputted into the same input field?

The [v-text-field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/) component in Vuetify lets you select date and time together if you set `type="datetime-local"` instead of `"date"`.

[image: vuetify date input]

Explanation of `datetime-local`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: Good solution for Vuetify 3 as of right now, because there is no `v-datepicker` so far

Answer (score 2):

In HTML way, you can use datetime-local as type

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="datetime">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <v-text-field
              label="Data di nascita"
              color="primary"
              persistentPlaceholder
              :placeholder="birthDate.toLocaleDateString()"
              :value="birthDate.toLocaleDateString()"
            >
              <template #append-inner>
                <v-btn icon flat
                  ><v-icon>mdi-calendar</v-icon>
                  <v-menu activator="parent">
                    <v-date-picker
                      color="primary"
                      hideHeader
                      hideWeekdays
                      v-model="birthDate"
                    >
                    </v-date-picker>
                  </v-menu>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
            </v-text-field>
```

I used `v-date-picker` component inside of a `v-menu` which goes in the `v-slot='append-inner'`